# makefile "C:\Program" not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: windows, makefile

I am trying to run make after downloading source for lua, but I am getting an error that says

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
make: *** [guess] Error 1
```

I understand that some people got this error due to not placing any quotation marks around the path, but right now I am just running make without specifying any path. How should I go around this?

---EDIT--
This is the makefile I tried to run

```
# Makefile for installing Lua
# See doc/readme.html for installation and customization instructions.

# == CHANGE THE SETTINGS BELOW TO SUIT YOUR ENVIRONMENT =======================

# Your platform. See PLATS for possible values.
PLAT= guess

# Where to install. The installation starts in the src and doc directories,
# so take care if INSTALL_TOP is not an absolute path. See the local target.
# You may want to make INSTALL_LMOD and INSTALL_CMOD consistent with
# LUA_ROOT, LUA_LDIR, and LUA_CDIR in luaconf.h.
INSTALL_TOP= /usr/local
INSTALL_BIN= '$(INSTALL_TOP)/bin'
INSTALL_INC= '$(INSTALL_TOP)/include'
INSTALL_LIB= '$(INSTALL_TOP)/lib'
INSTALL_MAN= '$(INSTALL_TOP)/man/man1'
INSTALL_LMOD= '$(INSTALL_TOP)/share/lua/$V'
INSTALL_CMOD= '$(INSTALL_TOP)/lib/lua/$V'

# How to install. If your install program does not support "-p", then
# you may have to run ranlib on the installed liblua.a.
INSTALL= install -p
INSTALL_EXEC= $(INSTALL) -m 0755
INSTALL_DATA= $(INSTALL) -m 0644
#
# If you don't have "install" you can use "cp" instead.
# INSTALL= cp -p
# INSTALL_EXEC= $(INSTALL)
# INSTALL_DATA= $(INSTALL)

# Other utilities.
MKDIR= mkdir -p
RM= rm -f

# == END OF USER SETTINGS -- NO NEED TO CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE =======

# Convenience platforms targets.
PLATS= guess aix bsd c89 freebsd generic linux linux-readline macosx mingw posix solaris

# What to install.
TO_BIN= lua luac
TO_INC= lua.h luaconf.h lualib.h lauxlib.h lua.hpp
TO_LIB= liblua.a
TO_MAN= lua.1 luac.1

# Lua version and release.
V= 5.4
R= $V.2

# Targets start here.
all:    $(PLAT)

$(PLATS) help test clean:
    @cd src && $(MAKE) $@

install: dummy
    cd src && $(MKDIR) $(INSTALL_BIN) $(INSTALL_INC) $(INSTALL_LIB) $(INSTALL_MAN) $(INSTALL_LMOD) $(INSTALL_CMOD)
    cd src && $(INSTALL_EXEC) $(TO_BIN) $(INSTALL_BIN)
    cd src && $(INSTALL_DATA) $(TO_INC) $(INSTALL_INC)
    cd src && $(INSTALL_DATA) $(TO_LIB) $(INSTALL_LIB)
    cd doc && $(INSTALL_DATA) $(TO_MAN) $(INSTALL_MAN)

uninstall:
    cd src && cd $(INSTALL_BIN) && $(RM) $(TO_BIN)
    cd src && cd $(INSTALL_INC) && $(RM) $(TO_INC)
    cd src && cd $(INSTALL_LIB) && $(RM) $(TO_LIB)
    cd doc && cd $(INSTALL_MAN) && $(RM) $(TO_MAN)

local:
    $(MAKE) install INSTALL_TOP=../install

# make may get confused with install/ if it does not support .PHONY.
dummy:

# Echo config parameters.
echo:
    @cd src && $(MAKE) -s echo
    @echo "PLAT= $(PLAT)"
    @echo "V= $V"
    @echo "R= $R"
    @echo "TO_BIN= $(TO_BIN)"
    @echo "TO_INC= $(TO_INC)"
    @echo "TO_LIB= $(TO_LIB)"
    @echo "TO_MAN= $(TO_MAN)"
    @echo "INSTALL_TOP= $(INSTALL_TOP)"
    @echo "INSTALL_BIN= $(INSTALL_BIN)"
    @echo "INSTALL_INC= $(INSTALL_INC)"
    @echo "INSTALL_LIB= $(INSTALL_LIB)"
    @echo "INSTALL_MAN= $(INSTALL_MAN)"
    @echo "INSTALL_LMOD= $(INSTALL_LMOD)"
    @echo "INSTALL_CMOD= $(INSTALL_CMOD)"
    @echo "INSTALL_EXEC= $(INSTALL_EXEC)"
    @echo "INSTALL_DATA= $(INSTALL_DATA)"

# Echo pkg-config data.
pc:
    @echo "version=$R"
    @echo "prefix=$(INSTALL_TOP)"
    @echo "libdir=$(INSTALL_LIB)"
    @echo "includedir=$(INSTALL_INC)"

# Targets that do not create files (not all makes understand .PHONY).
.PHONY: all $(PLATS) help test clean install uninstall local dummy echo pc

# (end of Makefile)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the respective Makefile in your question.

Comment: Also note that `make` really doesn't like paths with spaces in them.

Comment: running make without any path is not related to Lua, tag removed. feel free to tag lua again once you've added some Lua related content to your question

Comment: @G.M. But I never specify any path. I just ran make without any arguments. I am not quite sure where it is even getting C:\Programs Files from

Comment: This `Makefile` isn't meant to be used in Windows.

Comment: You can run this Makefile on Windows from MinGW